# Unable to load images in error page using nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

My goal is to display a static message for all the application URI path whenever I start nginx.
Below is my location block and it works fine when I use the URL https://localhost:5443/abc/def

```
      location /abc {
                proxy_pass "https://localhost:5443/";
        }
```

Now when I enter the URL "https://localhost:5443/abc/def/ghi" I cannot see the images in the HTML page, below is my error block

```
     error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
                location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                 internal;
         }
```

This is what I see in the error log
"/usr/share/nginx/html/def/ghi" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET //def/ghi HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost:5443

How can I point all the URL path to a URL which displays the custom message correctly

I tried to display a custom error page for nginx but it is not working when I have multiple URL path, how can I redirect all the URL path to a single working URL so that my error page is loaded correctly